# Installing perl switch using CPAN is failing

Tags: perl, cpan

I pasted the output below  (originally posted to http://pastebin.com/Sh7a8tHK)

```
cpan[1]> install Switch
Reading '/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Tue, 11 Dec 2012 05:55:05 GMT
Running install for module 'Switch'
Running make for R/RG/RGARCIA/Switch-2.16.tar.gz
Checksum for /.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RG/RGARCIA/Switch-2.16.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

CPAN.pm: Building R/RG/RGARCIA/Switch-2.16.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Switch
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp Switch.pm blib/lib/Switch.pm
Manifying blib/man3/Switch.3
RGARCIA/Switch-2.16.tar.gz
/usr/ccs/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /opt/perl/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/given.t ... Useless use of numeric gt (>) in void context at t/given.t line 19.
t/given.t ... Failed 2/293 subtests
t/nested.t .. ok
t/switch.t .. ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/given.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 293 Failed: 2)
Failed tests:  2-3
Files=3, Tests=590,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.07 usr  0.01 sys +  0.47 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.55 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/3 test programs. 2/590 subtests failed.
*** Error code 255
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `test_dynamic'
RGARCIA/Switch-2.16.tar.gz
/usr/ccs/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
reports RGARCIA/Switch-2.16.tar.gz
Running make install
make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
RGARCIA/Switch-2.16.tar.gz                   : make_test NO

cpan[2]>
```

There seems to be a problem with the module as evidenced by "Useless use of numeric gt.....", however I installed this module fine on a different machine using CPAN.  This is the only module CPAN is complaining about when installing.

I am using the latest version of perl 5.16:

```
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 2 (v5.16.2) built for i86pc-solaris
```

How can I install this module?

NOTE: Please do not tell me Switch is deprecated.  I understand that.

Comment: Please don't use pastebin.  If the text is in pastebin, then future users cannot find this question based on the errors you've reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
use feature qw/switch/;
```

See

```
perldoc -q switch
```

Comment: Since switch (given\when) is now built in why do I have to do use feature qw/switch/;?  Either way it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: For backwards compatibility. If it was always on, it would break existing programs with subs named `given` and `when`.

Comment: `use 5.010` automatically enables `given`/`when`, also.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to *The Effective Perler* article [Use for() instead of given()](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/05/use-for-instead-of-given/) if you're OK to use Perl v5.10 or later.

Comment: In 5.018 [`given `](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements) will alias like [`for`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) currently does.

Answer (score 0):

Patch:

`--- Switch-2.16-wjgfvU/Switch.pm   2009-10-23 00:52:51.000000000 -0700`

`+++ Switch-2.16-wjgfvUcopy/Switch.pm   2010-08-15 17:41:38.000000000 -0700`

```
@@ -146,7 +146,7 @@ sub filter_blocks
die "Bad $keyword statement (problem in the code block?) near $Switch::file line ", line(substr($source,0, pos $source), $line), "\n";
        };
my $code = filter_blocks(substr($source,$pos[0],$pos[4]-$pos[0]),line(substr($source,0,$pos[0]),$line));
-           $code =~ s/{/{ local \$::_S_W_I_T_C_H; Switch::switch $arg;/;
+           $code =~ s/{/{ local \$::_S_W_I_T_C_H; Switch::switch($arg);/;
            $text .= $code . 'continue {last}';
            next component;
        }
```